Detecting actual CRS when coordinate in WGS84 is known
My geodataframe includes some points of unknown coordinate reference system, each point has address as well, so I am able to find coordinates for them in WGS84.
An example point is: POINT (472593.82615019 573557.105385679),I know the coordinate in WGS84 should be approximately POINT (20.9434625 52.208522).
So far I tried to bet proper origin CRS and get point in WGS84 closely to the POINT (20.9434625 52.208522).
from shapely.geometry import Point
import pyproj

origin_proj = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:3395') #cartesian
wgs_proj = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong', datum='WGS84')

x = 472593.82615019
y = 573557.105385679

new_lon, new_lat = pyproj.transform(origin_proj, wgs_proj, x, y)

I tried to use several origin projections, but I didn't get any of point of WGS84 that would be close to expected one.
Do you have any hints how to detect the origin crs?

How do you know that that coordinate should be at that particular place in WGS84?

@Erik  OP has addresses for the points so is using some sort of geocoder--maybe nothing better than Google maps.

The only way really is to try all possible projection codes until you hit one that matches close enough. In python, you'd have to loop over a few thousand EPSG:abcde strings, and make sure you catch failures such as invalid coordinates in those projections.
There is a web site that does this if you have a small number of cases to find, projfinder.com, where you centre the map roughly where you think your point is, put the coordinates in the X and Y box, then it will find projections that hit locations near the map centre.
Trying it with your numbers, the map centre cross-hair is roughly on your WGS84 origin, and the numbers in the box are your coordinates, and it finds two projections that give locations somewhat north-west of your possible location (and a third we can ignore) marked by yellow dots. Are these close enough? Can you try other examples? Did I type all the numbers in correctly and did I get X-Y and lat-long the right way round?


Tried the same on epsg.io, but the coordinates are off by about 200 km when converting to UTM34N

Yes, but when someone gives coordinates the nanometre I just accept there's no clue to the actual required precision :)
